# KIF iOS test failures with Apple's CI Bots

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, automated-tests, kif, xcode-bots

I continue to have most of my KIF UI Test cases fail with Apple's CI Bots.

The errors I get are: "Failed to find accessibility element with label ...."

I can run all and pass the tests consistently on the same machine just fine with a Command U, but when running from an Xcode bot they fail (but intermittently and inconsistently.) For example, sometimes 24/25 tests will fail with the bot and the next time 20/25 tests fail with the same bot, with no changes. Furthermore, the first few tests I ran when I initially set up the bot ran and passed perfectly.

I am running the tests on the iOS 9 Simulator Xcode 7.1 and Version 10.11.1 OS X Server.

Has anyone experienced and resolved similar UI Automated Testing issues with Xcode bots themselves?

Comment: After testing on a Mac Pro the UI tests are passing consistently. The previous test machine was a mac mini with 8 gigs ram. Thus, if you encounter something similar with your UI Tests and Xcode bots, beef up your hardware to see if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is hardware.

After testing on a Mac Pro the UI tests are passing consistently. The previous test machine was a mac mini with 8 gigs ram. Thus, if you encounter something similar with your UI Tests and Xcode bots, beef up your hardware to see if that helps.